# Text not updating in PySimpleGui

Tags: python, pysimplegui

In my code, Im trying to make a calculator. So there is a `1` button which when pressed, updates the `Question:`  text by adding `1` to it's text. So when I press `1`, the text will convert from `Question:`  to `Question: 1`. But its not updating. I have faced this problem before too. I think when I do the `.update`, it will only update the value till its the same number of letters as the text already has. If it has 2 letters and I try to `.update('123')`, it will only update to `12`. Is there any way to get around this???

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

layout = [
    [sg.Text('Question: ', key='-IN-')],
    [sg.Text('Answer will be shown here', key='-OUT-')],
    [sg.Button('1'), sg.Button('2'), sg.Button('3')],
    [sg.Button('4'), sg.Button('5'), sg.Button('6')],
    [sg.Button('7'), sg.Button('8'), sg.Button('9')],
    [sg.Button('Enter'), sg.Button('Exit')]
]

window = sg.Window('calculator', layout)

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event is None or event == 'Exit':
        break
    elif event == '1':
        bleh = window['-IN-'].get()
        teh = f'{bleh}1'
        window['-IN-'].update(value=teh)

window.close()
```

Comment: I am a beginner to PySimpleGui so 

Comment: It is caused by the length of text element, it will be length of initial string if option `size` not defined. So you did update, but not shown for too long to show on short text element. Suggest you use `sg.InputText` with option `readonly=True`.

Comment: @JasonYang tysm for the answer!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As above comment, Example like this,

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

layout = [
    [sg.InputText('Question: ', readonly=True, key='-IN-')],
    [sg.Text('Answer will be shown here', key='-OUT-')],
    [sg.Button('1'), sg.Button('2'), sg.Button('3')],
    [sg.Button('4'), sg.Button('5'), sg.Button('6')],
    [sg.Button('7'), sg.Button('8'), sg.Button('9')],
    [sg.Button('Enter'), sg.Button('Exit')]
]

window = sg.Window('calculator', layout)
input = window['-IN-']
while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event is None or event == 'Exit':
        break
    elif event in '1234567890':
        bleh = window['-IN-'].get()
        teh = f'{bleh}{event}'
        input.update(value=teh)
        input.Widget.xview("end")   # view end if text is too long to fit element

window.close()
```